# How to get mounting url from router in Express.js

Tags: express

All:

I wonder if I define router, how to get which base url it is mount?

For example:

**My question here is: for the full path is /user/welcome, how to get the base url: /user in user router**

```
// user.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get("/welcome", function(req, res){res.send("Welcome!");})


// app.js
var user = require('user')
var app = express();
app.use("/user", user);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you exporting from user.js ? router ?

If yes, just do in **user.js** :

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var url = req.originalUrl; 
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, the router.